# Why does Graphics2D drawImage take so much time?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe

I am creating a game that utilizes the Java Graphics2D library. The following call in a simplified version of my code is taking around 20 ms to complete:

```
off2.drawImage(tileImage, 0, 0, null);
```

where `tileImage` is an image of size 5040 * 2280, and `off2` is declared via the following code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice device = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration config = device.getDefaultConfiguration();
offscreen = config.createCompatibleImage(SCREEN WIDTH, SCREEN HEIGHT, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
offg = offscreen.getGraphics();
off2 = (Graphics2D)offg;
```

I also use `off2.scale` to scale my images.

I have a `paintComponent` method in a class that inherits `JPanel` that draws `offscreen`:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);                 
}
```

I was wondering if this amount of time is to be expected for a single call. Seeing that it is an action game, I would prefer to use the fastest methods possible to maximize smoothness.

Comment: Are you always rendering the entire image?  If so, why?  You should render the part that's on-screen (fewer pixels).

Comment: @JacobG. Very good point. Thanks. I'm pretty new, so how would you go about rendering only part of an image?

Comment: Depends.  Is it a static image?  If so, I guess you can render it fully once when it's needed for the first time, and just cache it.

Comment: *5040 * 2280*  - If you need double buffering, maybe consider using a `BufferStrategy`